# iOS - Looping through subviews

Tags: ios, subview

I am trying to loop all my subviews and print them in NSLog.
I have developed this recursive method:

```
- (void)allSubViews:(UIView*)mainV
{
    for (UIView *view in mainV.subviews) {
        NSLog(@"%@", view);
        if ([[view subviews]count]>0) {
            [self allSubViews:view];
        }
    }
}
```

which I call from **MainViewController.m**:

```
[self allSubViews:self.myView];
```

The result is:

> 2015-09-12 11:18:48.919 Profile-Statistics[3153:506562] <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fc70bf1c330; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES;
>   layer = >
>
> 2015-09-12 11:18:48.919 Profile-Statistics[3153:506562] <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fc70bf1ced0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES;
>   layer = >

My View has Top and Bottom Layout Guide and a View which has 3 UIButtons, 1 ImageView and 1 UIView.

Did I miss something here?

**Update:**
Screenshot of StoryBoard

[image]

Comment: does these buttons and imageviews are inside the mainView? or self.view?

Comment: `myView` is the main view

Comment: these subviews are inside myView right?

Comment: Yes! Actually myView is self.view.

Comment: I've tried your code at my end and it runs perfectly. Which makes me think that maybe you haven't added the views correctly. Could you show the storyboard screen?

Comment: Also, you can shorten your code to this `- (void)allSubViews:(UIView*)mainV
{
    for (UIView *view in mainV.subviews) {
        NSLog(@"%@", view);
        [self allSubViews:view];
    }
}`
and it would still work.

Comment: I agree with @ShamasS, I think the code is correct but the views aren't embedded as you expect. If you show the Document Outline (button on bottom left of the storyboard screen) you'll see the hierarchy of views. I suspect that the buttons are not actually subviews of `self.myView`.

Comment: If you run your method by calling `[self allSubViews:self.view];` (note `self.view` not `self.myView`) you should see the recursive list of all subviews to confirm that your method logic is correct.

Comment: Hi! On the document outline there all under the "View"

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I tried this in a sample project with a bunch of subviews and it worked as expected.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)printButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [self allSubviews:self.view];
}

- (void) allSubviews:(UIView*) parent {
    NSLog(@"%@", parent);
    for (UIView *child in parent.subviews) {
        [self allSubviews:child];
    }
}

@end
```

Console output is:

```
2015-09-13 22:06:00.904 RecursivePrint[66243:3455899] <UIView: 0x7fa902e0e6e0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa902e15030>>
2015-09-13 22:06:00.905 RecursivePrint[66243:3455899] <UIView: 0x7fa902e0e840; frame = (70 56; 452 337); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa902e15050>>
2015-09-13 22:06:00.905 RecursivePrint[66243:3455899] <UIView: 0x7fa902e24c90; frame = (31 33; 153 160); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa902e21f00>>
2015-09-13 22:06:00.906 RecursivePrint[66243:3455899] <UIView: 0x7fa902e24fc0; frame = (219 41; 153 160); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa902e1ec10>>
2015-09-13 22:06:00.906 RecursivePrint[66243:3455899] <UIButton: 0x7fa902d177e0; frame = (164.5 603; 46 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa902d16c80>>
2015-09-13 22:06:00.907 RecursivePrint[66243:3455899] <UIButtonLabel: 0x7fa902d1f010; frame = (0 6; 46 18); text = 'Button'; alpha = 0.2; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fa902d1f670>>
2015-09-13 22:06:00.907 RecursivePrint[66243:3455899] <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fa902e25ed0; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa902e21b20>>
2015-09-13 22:06:00.907 RecursivePrint[66243:3455899] <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7fa902f77ec0; frame = (0 667; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa902f09f70>>
```

As a side note, this is the first time in over a year that I've tried to do something in Objective-C. The Swift version seems so much easier to understand:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func printButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        printSubviews(self.view)
    }
}

func printSubviews(parent:UIView) {
    print(parent)
    for child in parent.subviews {
        printSubviews(child)
    }
}
```

In addition, the Swift version of `printSubviews` is defined as a function, not a method so you don't call it from `self`, you just call it with the top level view you want to start with.